# Можно ли поставить два двоеточия?

Tags: двоеточие

Личная просьба: приобретите, пожалуйста, ребятам бейджи с именами: чтобы учителя и ученики смогли быстрее друг друга запомнить.

Comment: Может и можно, но не нужно. Не вижу необходимости во втором двоеточии. Зачем оно вам?

Comment: @Виктория пожалуйста, если вас устроил мой ответ, поставьте галочку) Так я пойму, что помог решить ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Два двоеточия **могут** быть в одном предложении, хотя зачастую, чтобы избежать их скопления, одно из двоеточий заменяют на тире.

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

> 1. Если несколько частей сложного предложения последовательно связаны значениями причины, пояснения (возможна подстановка союзов потому что, а именно), то, вопреки общему правилу (и в том и в другом случае правила предусматривают постановку двоеточия), возможна замена одного из двоеточий знаком тире для передачи разных оттенков значения. Ср. примеры: Было жалко Алпатову Гуська: с этим стариком связывалось всё лучшее в детстве и всегда казалось: из всех людей на
>    свете нет лучше и нет роднее Гуська (Пришв.). — Было жалко Алпатову Гуська: с этим стариком связывалось всё лучшее в детстве и всегда казалось — из всех людей на свете нет лучше и нет роднее Гуська; Фрол хорошо знал Степана. Случилось так, как он, наверно, ждал: нервы Степана напряглись до предела, он не выдержал: заслышав шаги казака, стремительно вышагнул навстречу ему (Шукш.) — ...Случилось так, как он, наверно, ждал: нервы Степана напряглись до предела, он не выдержал — заслышав шаги казака, стремительно вышагнул навстречу ему (двоеточие указывает на основное членение предложения, а тире является внутренним знаком).

**В вашем же случае** двоеточие перед *чтобы* стоять не должно: это сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным цели; части сложноподчинённого предложения разделяются **запятыми**.

Таким образом, никаких оснований для постановки второго двоеточия в вашем предложении нет!

Итак, корректное предложение:

***Личная просьба: приобретите, пожалуйста, ребятам бейджи с именами, чтобы учителя и ученики смогли быстрее друг друга запомнить.***